# Adding -fPIC option in Imake file

Tags: c++, linux, linker

I am making Makefile using Imakefile. 
I am getting compilation error.

```
 rm -f /vobs/eagle/build/linux/debug/lib/libTestRtip.so
/usr/bin/g++ -Wl,-soname,libTestRtip.so /vobs/eagle/build/linux/debug/obj/TestRtip.oo  -    L/vobs/eagle/build/linux/debug/lib -L/vobs-   ads/outsource/ace610_linux_64bit/ACE_wrappers/lib/linux -L/vobs-  ads/outsource/log4cxx/linux/lib64     -shared -o    /vobs/eagle/build/linux/debug/lib/libTestRtip.so
/usr/bin/ld: /vobs/eagle/build/linux/debug/obj/TestRtip.oo: relocation R_X86_64_32  against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/vobs/eagle/build/linux/debug/obj/TestRtip.oo: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/vobs/eagle/build/linux/debug/lib/libTestRtip.so] Error 1
```

I don't know where to add -fPIC in Imakefile.

Comment: Please post whole output of compilation

Answer (score 1):

**PIC** - Position Independent Code.
This is a flag (`-f`) for compiler to output object files with code independent of where it is located in the memory. This is usually a *must-have* for libraries (`.so`).

So, as I said it is a compiler flag, so you should look into your **Makefile** for `CFLAGS` varialbe and add it there.

Your CFLAGS may look like:

```
CFLAGS = -g -O0 -I/usr/local/include
```

And your job is to do:

```
CFLAGS = -g -O0 -I/usr/local/include -fPIC
```

---

Alternatively you can make like this:

```
$ make CFLAGS="-fPIC" all
```

Comment: I am using Imakefile to create Makefile

Comment: @user3153014, so read the docs and see where you can set compiler flags, I thought you've got the idea...