# CDT using lib*.a --- relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol ... can not be used

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I try to reference a static `*.a` library for my c++ project in CDT. I included it in

> C/C++ Build -> Cross C++ Linker -> Libraries

But I get the error:

> relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol ... can not be used when making a shared object.

Now from what I have read so far I think this means the compiler thinks I am referencing a shared library, when it is a static library instead - Is that the case and if so what can do now? Is there any way to just use the `*.a` libraries or do I have to recompile them as `.so` - objects?

Comment: Just wondering, what is this Cross C++ linker? Is it for cross-compilation?

Comment: @kiner_shah I'm not really sure what it is exactly. I was referring to a ledger in the CDT IDE, which is the C++ flavor of Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most probably coming from the fact that the static library is compiled without supporting [position independent code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5311538/6639989). I don't know a way to fix it without recompiling the static library.

If you can recompile the static library, then assuming you are using gcc or clang, you have to add the `-fPIC` flag to your compiler flags.

Without more information it is hard to give more advice. If you can provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then I can help you with that.

Comment: Could you add some reference to the flags to enable PIC eg in CMAKE and/or other common kind of makefiles? Thanks

Comment: For CMake [it is easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297422/6639989). For other build systems I am not 100% sure, but basically you have to extend the `CFLAGS` and/or `CXXFLAGS` with the `-fPIC` option. For unix makefiles, it looks like something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22803578/6639989).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had just compiled it as *.a, so I was pretty sure a recompile again as *.a wouldn't work, there was no chance gcc was updated in the meantime. So I tried what you mentioned in the question already: removed the .a libs and recompiled&installed as .so and it worked. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I had to recompile, but it sufficed to recompile as *.a library again. I'm pretty sure the problem originated from an update of my gcc compiler.